# jquery.Ajax data obtaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I try to obtain data stored in another url. There is a text field in which I want to set the value retrieved from the url at every 1 second(The url's content is continually changing at each second). How can I do that? I don't want refreshing **entire page** at each second. Instead, only the field must be refreshed. But, in my code, the field is not set as intended and it is empty.

What's wrong with my idea/approach?

Html,

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="" for="temperature">Temp.:</label>
<input type="text" id="temperature" class="form-control">
</div>
```

My ajax/jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax('/theURLData', {
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                $('#temperature').val(data);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: do `console.log(data);` before `$('#temperature').val(data);` and see what output you got in console. Tell us that output

Comment: Are you sure the call is successful?   Check the network tab of the dev tools window and verify the response

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think `setInterval(function()…` works as intended here. Try the following,

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function f() {
    $.ajax('/theURLData', {
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            $('#temperature').val(data);
            setTimeout(f, 1000);
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```